# How can I select all order numbers with operations, but limit some orders based on an operations time?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that currently pulls all order numbers and operations based on a work center.

I have it set to specifically leave out 2 operations (in WHERE statement)

```
     AND operation NOT IN ('Test1', 'Test2')
```

I need to change this to include these operations, but, only if they have been there for under x amount of time. I do have a column with a start date to work with in format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.0000000'

an example of the columns I am working with are:

```
    Order    operation    start_date
    AW1234     Test1     2016-10-02 20:18:39.0000000
    WEFDO43    Test2     2016-10-02 04:18:39.0000000
    WEFVO43    OP1     2016-10-02 04:18:39.0000000
    WEXJO43    LITTLE     2016-10-02 04:18:39.0000000
    WEBJO43    BIG    2016-10-02 04:18:39.0000000
    WEWJO43    TIN     2016-10-02 04:18:39.0000000
```

I have tried adding it to 'WHERE' and creating a CASE, but i get lost at the end

```
    --, (SELECT CASE WHEN w.operation like '%FAR-CMPHLD%' AND Need_Date < getdate() - 6 ....ELSE END...)
```

how can I add these operations' order numbers if they have been started in the last X amount of days without changing the original query?

I am using SQL server 2012

Comment: Is `start_date` a `varchar` in a particular format?  Or a `datetime`?

Comment: Add a Union and keep the Test1 and Test2 in a separate query.

Comment: @JustinCave it is an nvarchar(50)

Comment: @WEI_DBA, I messed around with a union, this portion of the query is nested inside 2 other select statements which caused confusion and made it very long. looking for something clean and simple

Comment: Ah.  That does make life rather more complicated.  Is there a reason that you're using the wrong data type?  Are you fine with the query blowing up (potentially seemlingly randomly) if a single row in the table has a string in the wrong format?

Comment: @JustinCave lol no :) can you elaborate on what would blow up and why? still a newbie to SQL...

Comment: Well, when you use the wrong data type then if you want to do anything involving date arithmetic, you have to convert the string to a date.  If one row has the wrong format, that conversion will error out and the query will throw an error.  In normal operations, though, you'll have different predicates being applied and the database is free to apply them in whatever order it expects will be most efficient (which may change over time) so if you have a few bad rows, the query might run successfully 90% of the time because it filters out the bad row before the conversion fails

Comment: while it fails 10% of the time because it tries to do a conversion on a row before filtering it out for some other reason.  That sort of seemingly random failure can be a real bear to debug.  Plus, if the query plan changes, it's entirely possible that the query would work perfectly in dev and test and in the first few months in prod and then suddenly start failing every time because the optimizer picked a different plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up adding a UNION inside of my original code, nested code like below:

```
               SELECT *
               FROM
               (*Original code*
                SELECT *
                FROM Testing1 w, Testing2 so
                WHERE w.Site = 'OROR'
                AND so.shop = w.shop
                AND w.operation NOT IN ('Test1', 'Test2') 
                AND convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 10

                UNION

                SELECT *
                FROM Testing1 w, Testing2 so
                WHERE w.Site = 'OROR'
                AND so.shop = w.shop
                AND w.operation Like('Test1') 
                AND convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 8

                UNION

                SELECT *
                FROM Testing1 w, Testing2 so
                WHERE w.Site = 'OROR'
                AND so.shop = w.shop
                AND w.operation Like('Test2') 
                AND convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 4) b
```

doing it this way allowed me to select these operations separately and control the amount of time they have been at that operation, since they needed to be different

would have liked a simpler version, but this one runs great

Answer (score 0):

All you should need is `OR`, like:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   Testing1 w inner join 
   Testing2 so on
   so.shop = w.shop and
   w.Site = 'OROR'
WHERE
   (w.operation = 'Test1' AND 
convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 8) OR
   (w.operation = 'Test2' AND 
convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 4) OR
   (w.operation NOT IN ('Test1', 'Test2') AND 
convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 10 )
```

or even:

```
SELECT *
FROM 
   Testing1 w inner join 
   Testing2 so on
   so.shop = w.shop and
   w.Site = 'OROR'  AND 
   convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 10
WHERE
   (w.operation = 'Test1' AND 
convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 8) OR
   (w.operation = 'Test2' AND 
convert(Date, actual_start_date, 120) >= GETDATE() - 4) OR
   (w.operation NOT IN ('Test1', 'Test2'))
```